# XSLT and entity references

Tags: xslt

i have xml looks like:

```
 <ProductPrice>
        <CurrencySymbol>€</CurrencySymbol>
        <Amount>4.15</Amount>
        <DependsOn>&gt; 500 €</DependsOn>
        <SiteGuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</SiteGuid>
        <Disabled>false</Disabled>
        <SortId>0</SortId>
  </ProductPrice>
```

How can i do with XSLT something like that?

```
<xsl:for-each select="./Prices/ProductPrice">
 <xsl:if test="DependsOn = '&gt; 500 €'">
   <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
   <xsl:text></xsl:text>
   <xsl:text>
   </xsl:text>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The if clause can´t work because of the entity reference.
Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 1):

> The if clause can´t work because of the entity reference. Any
>   solutions for that?

**There is *no* problem and your code works as expected**.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:if test="DependsOn = '&gt; 500 €'">
        <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
        <xsl:text></xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<ProductPrice>
    <CurrencySymbol>€</CurrencySymbol>
    <Amount>4.15</Amount>
    <DependsOn>&gt; 500 €</DependsOn>
    <SiteGuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</SiteGuid>
    <Disabled>false</Disabled>
    <SortId>0</SortId>
</ProductPrice>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
4.15
```

Comment: Hello Dimitre, thanks for your answer. I use Saxon and AntillesXML - could be the problem there? In my XSLT i query with the same syntax other fields(without "&gt;") without problems. Because of that i think the problem must be at the processor. Which processor do you use?

Comment: @datÜlfchen: The result I posted was produced with Saxon 6.5.4

Comment: There's certainly no reason why your code shouldn't work. Are you sure it's not a problem with the encoding of the Euro symbol?